# Submitting a given number of times the same form: Why is this code not working?

Tags: php, forms, yii2

So I am making a quiz in which the user gets confronted with a succession of questions which he answers through a form.
The series of problems each contain a given number of questions, and the questions get asked one after the other when the user validates.

I am therefore trying to re-render the view with the form for each problem until they're all done. This is my action:

```
public function actionAnswer($id_serie)
{
    if ($id_serie != 0)                          //getting the serie's info
    {
        $serie = Serie::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id_serie])
            ->one();
        $problems = (new \yii\db\Query())        //getting the problems in the serie
            ->select('*')
            ->from('problems')
            ->where(['id_serie' => $id_serie])
            ->all();
        $prob_counter = $serie->nbr_of_problems; //counts the number of questions answered
        $id_serie = 0;
    }
    $model = new Answer;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
    {
        $model->save();     // works just fine every time
        if (--$prob_counter <= 0)
        {
            return $this->redirect('index.php?r=student/entry');
        }
    }
    return $this->render('answer',
            ['model' => $model,
            'problems' => $problems,
            'serie' => $serie,
            'prob_counter' => $prob_counter,       //these last two are for debug
            'id_serie' => $id_serie]);
}
```

When this action gets executed the first time, $id_serie is never null or =0. Hence I am using this to query the db only once and set a counter to the total number of problems in the serie. (id est the number of time the user has to submit the form)
If his answer is valid, I decrement my counter and if it falls under 0, there are no questions to answer anymore and the user gets redirected.

However, this counter never goes down to 0: it is set correctly, it is decremented only once, and then it never falls lower, no matter where I put the line. (inside or outside any loop)
On the other hand the data from the form is properly inserted in the db each time.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, `$prob_counter` just stores the number of problems for each series. You need to change this to show the number of unanswered problems for the series. How you implement this will depend on your models and database but it should be something like:

```
$problems = (new \yii\db\Query())        //getting the problems in the serie
        ->select('*')
        ->from('problems')
        ->where(['id_serie' => $id_serie])
        ->andWhere('not exists (select id from answer where problemid = problems.id')
        ->all();
```

Also you should probably look at [working with relational data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data) and avoid using `Query()` in the above section.

Comment: I (think I) understand what you are saying, but I rather not get the remaining problems each time my action gets executed. I'm using a trick with $id_serie in order to get all the problems at first exec, and keep them for as long as the user hasn't answered all of them. $prob_counter is not intented to just store the number of problems, it's a counter that is to be set once and decremented each time we render answering form view. I still don't get what's wrong with my implementation... Are the variables' value not persistent between two runs? Is the trick with $id_serie wrong?

Comment: Unless you are saving the values to session or the database, the values are not persistent.